# If silicon wafers can only be made round, why are the chips we make not hexagons instead of squares to cover the edges more efficiently?

Tags: lithography

The thread is closed but the logic still checks out.  Hexagons, octagons, etc.  are more efficient to fill a circle than squares.

If a transistor has three leads shouldn't it be a triangle?

6 triangles make a hexagon right?

[Closed Reddit thread that asked this question.](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/20f6ts/if_silicon_wafers_can_only_be_made_round_why_are/)

Comment: Have you ever tried to cut a bunch of hexagons out of a sheet?

Comment: A round sheet? No. why do we have to cut the wafer? Just run the whole thing and sell the runtime/

Comment: Any shaped sheet. Think about how many cuts do you need to make. Now think about how short each edge of a tiny hexagon has to be and how tiny the saw blade needs to be to squeeze in there.

Comment: I need to make 0 cuts.

Comment: You do realize many hundreds or thousands of chips are made from one wafer and at some point someone has to cut it up into individual chips, right?

Comment: The answers in that reddit thread seem correct to me.  Cutting hexagons would be harder and the reticle is actually exposing using a square/rectangular mask anyway, so hexagons would actually be less efficient (more dead space between dies).

Comment: Dealing with hexagonal chips would become a pain at some later manufacturing stage too.  You'd either end up fitting the hexagonal chips in square cases or you'd have much more complicated to model motherboard layouts.  Trying to make a BGA chip work properly is hard enough without introducing a more complicated 3 axis grid.

Comment: @KH Well, depending how far you are willing to stretch the logic you can always say just make boards and packages hex as well. And all the same reasons about why not to would still apply.

Comment: @DKNguyen that's kind of what I mean.  It could be done, but at any stage it turns X and Y coordinate systems a human can easily deal with if need be into something more complicated that will either be a lot more work to layout or require computer assistance.

Comment: I suspect bees in our galaxy like hexagon, Bees in other galaxies like pentagon, stupid and lazy bees in stupid galaxies use square or triangle etc. It take bees many millions of years for the queens to evolve engineering trade off and cost benefit analysis.

Comment: @user1850479 You actually could make hexagonal die quite easily with modern, or even decades old lithography systems. No wasted space on the wafer is necessary (would waste space on the mask. But those rarely are full anyway). It isnt done because it is a pain to dice.

Comment: @Matt  Doesn't wasted space on the mask translate either into wasted space on the die or the need to step the mask into more positions on the wafer (and therefore fewer wafers per hour)?

Comment: @user1850479 Maybe, I guess you would normally tile your design to fill as mask mask space as possible. But there is always going to be "wasted" space, unless your die is an integer multiple of the usable mask area. I was picturing a situation where you can fit a very large number of die on your mask. I dont think there would be much of a difference in the number of steps there. If you have one die on the mask the number of steps wont change at all. Note: in the hex case the rectangular bounding box of your exposures will appear to overlap but the exposed regions wont.

Comment: @user1850479 Also, the systems Im familiar with (although they are a bit old, maybe it has changed) usually have a circular usable region on the mask. Hex tiling might really help there. (Its still not a good plan overall though)

Comment: I think this question truly is "beyond your minds [sic] capacity". The sum experience here is probably thousands of person-years. If you want to ignore the collective advice of those people, offering the most vague of reasons, good luck to you.

Comment: Kevin, I'm not seeing significant experience with VLSI design, fabrication, or test in your resume. Please give serious consideration to the feedback you are getting here.

Answer (score 11):

1. The edges of a wafer are not useful for manufacturing so there is already some waste there.
2. Areas around the edge of a wafer (and some internal spots) that you think might be wasted are actually used for test circuits. These test transistors are evaluated by the manufacturing fab to validate that the wafer was processed correctly before giving them to the customer. If the test transistors anywhere around the edge are out of tolerance then this means something in the process shifted and yield of the die may suffer.
3. It is easier to cut straight across the wafer with a saw. One doesn’t saw along the edge of one die right up to the next one like with a jigsaw. Therefore only a four sided polygon is possible. If you wanted a hexagon die, then your cuts through the wafer would not only double because you now have diagonal cuts but you would end up sawing right through the neighboring die.
4. Many die are very small, so they pack in around the edges of the wafer quite efficiently already. Sure, some die are very large, but then again that is why you pay a premium for an eight core Pentium. (The cost to process a wafer is nearly constant, but die size determines how much it costs per die to manufacture.)
5. Some die are constrained in their dimension and size due to application. For example, a display row/column driver die would be very narrow and very long, on the order of a 1x10 ratio, or greater. They cannot be hexagonal.

Those are the reasons that came to my mind.

Comment: I will add that a hexagonal die might actually be easier for bond wires from the pad ring around the die to the lead frame when packaging. The bond wires can get a little dense right around the corners.

Comment: 1) SMU 2) The fabricator is the end user 3) The wafer is not being cut 4) The edge chip-lets are implemented for alpha partial mitigation.

Comment: technically triangular dice are also possible, but as triangles have worse perimiter to area ratio than a squares that's rarely done.

Comment: @kpie are you talking wafer scale integration?

Comment: if the wafer is not going  to be diced, then you'd think that a circle would be the best shape.

Comment: @Kartman What would you do with an 8" silicon wafer? I don't see a situation where this really makes sense. The silicon defect density is going to make significant parts of the wafer unusable...best to keep the good bits and throw out the bad.

Comment: You actually can buy laser wafer dicing tools that let you cut arbitrary shapes. I imagine they are much slower than traditional mechanical systems. They arent commonly used, probably because there is no benefit to doing so.

Comment: @Matt Very interesting. I'll have to ask about that. As you say, expect speed and cost vs benefit over the traditional diamond saw might be why is isn't widespread. Certainly would be useful in specialized applications. Which reminds me... I have another reason for the answer above...